# How to run curl command to call rest api with spring security implemented

Tags: curl, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot

I implemented LDAP authentication with Spring Security in a Spring Boot Application. User credentials are passed in through a http login form. Username is taken as `{0}` in `.userDnPatterns("cn={0},ou=institution,ou=people")`. However, if I wanted to call rest api with curl command, how should I pass in the username and password from curl (or custom html page)? In other words, how to pass a variable from POST request to the config class?

My websecurityconfig class is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
            DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://ldap.xxx.edu:389/dc=mdanderson,dc=edu");
            contextSource.setUserDn("cn=ris_flow,ou=service accounts,ou=institution,ou=service accounts,dc=mdanderson,dc=edu");
            contextSource.setPassword("xxxyyyzzz");
            contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

            LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer = auth.ldapAuthentication();

            ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer
                .userDnPatterns("cn={0},ou=institution,ou=people")
                .userSearchBase("")
                .contextSource(contextSource);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

When I run

```
curl -d "username=djiao&password=xxxyyyzzz" http://localhost:8080/ristore/foundation/TRF134936
```

it returns nothing. The same url works in a browser though. By turning on verbose with `-v`, here is the output of the curl command.

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /ristore/foundation/TRF134936 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 35
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 35 out of 35 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=FE8C94FC8B445A2C8AA1FCFBB5F2826D; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Location: http://localhost:8080/login
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 27 Apr 2016 02:19:43 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: Maybe just one comment here: if you want to go for a Rest API I'd not use form login but either Basic Authentication or OAuth.

Comment: @daniel.eichten Agreed. form login is just something I wanted to test ldap authentication. Will definitely create html login page for Rest apis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man curl` is your friend. But in essence that is not as easy as with Basic Authentication. I mean you could potentially get passed the form auth by `POST`ing `username` and `password` if you don't use csrf (which you should).

```
curl -X POST -c cookies 'http://<host>:<port>/login' -d'username=<usernam>&password=<password>'
```

will allow you to send the credentials and using `-c cookies` to store the session cookie which you can then use for further requests. With csrf you'll have to request a csrf token upfront and extract it from the returned html, e.g. using some xpath expression.

Comment: If I give the username and password in the curl command like you suggested, do I need to make changes to my config class. Will it plug the username as `{0}` in `userDnPatterns=("cn={0},ou=institution,ou=people")` just like the native http login form?

Comment: Well if you are using the `cn` part as your username to login, then yes!

Comment: I guess the password will be handled as is too? I wonder if I were to deal with password explicitly in config, it would be `{1}`, right?

Comment: Well yes! You don't have to define this using a placeholder. If you configured spring-security-ldap correctly and it does work via a browser it will also work via `curl`. Spring will use the passed password to execute a second bind against your LDAP server.

Comment: How do I do a get request with `curl` when my Rest API is secured by LDAP authentication?

Comment: Your API is secured by form based authentication and the application behind it uses LDAP to authenticate. But for the `curl` command there isn't any difference if you use LDAP, InMemory or JDBC based authentication.